# Cant switch Docker OS on Window 8

Tags: windows, docker, operating-system

I have installed the Docker toolbox on Windows 8 and I am able to run Docker containers. However I don't have the Docker icon in the system tray and thus I can't change the Docker settings. Specifically I need to switch the Docker OS from Linux to Windows.

Is there a way how can I get the icon to be shown in the system tray? Has anyone ever had this issue?

Alternatively, is it possible to switch the Docker OS from CLI? According to the Docker forum I need to run SwitchDeamon, however I don't have this tool in the Docker installation folder and VisualStudio is also not able to switch the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/index#windows-container-types):

> Windows Containers include two different container types, or runtimes: Windows Server Containers & Hyper-V Isolation

This means windows container can only work with hyper-v or windows server 2016+, so if you not use server version, windows 10 professional which support hyper-v is a must to run windows container.

With `docker toolbox`(not `docker for windows`), you can just use virtualbox to run linux containers. So if you use windows7, windows8, windows10 home edition, then you surely use `docker toolbox`, then you can just use linux container.

Here also a [discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/can-i-run-windows-containers-using-docker-toolbox/46923) on docker forums.

As a result, there is no meaning to afford a switch on windows8 as `docker toolbox` just support linux container.